# Pass string value back to parent page

Tags: html, database, asp-classic

I am currently working with color palettes.

I have created an HTML page that displays 3 color palettes each with 15 different colors.

this is displayed as so -

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
<%
    old = 9999
    do while not rs.eof
%>
<% if old <> rs("palid") then %> 
<tr>
    <td> 
         <a href="tagcolours.asp?palid=<%=rs("palid")%>&Edit=<%=rs("palid")%>"> 
           <%=rs("palid")%>
         </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<% old = rs("palid") 
end if %>
<tr>
     <td onclick="myFunction()" 
         style="background-color:<%=(rs("Name") )%>">
         <%=(rs("Name") )%> 
     </td>
</tr>

<%
 rs.movenext
   loop
    rs.close
 conn.close
'end if
    %>
</table>
```

So based on the palette ID (`palid`) this determines what colors are shown.

When a user clicks on one of the colors (`Name`) values a new window is opened with all the available HTML colors for selection.

My problem being when a user clicks on one of the colors in the new window, I have it alerting that selection, but how could I take that string value, and update the first selection in the parent window with the new selection. For instance in the first page the color `GREEN` was needing to be changed to `RED` and that value had to be passed back to the first page and update the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.opener` method. window.opener property returns a reference to the window that created the window.

So you can access the parent window elements using this method. Have a look at the [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp)